# No Location Found In Geocoder Asyncktask Activity

Tags: android, google-maps, android-activity, android-asynctask, android-location

i want to build a app which shows me user location on google map...but it shows me no address is found ..even when i tried to give fixed value ...

```
     if(location!=null && !location.equals("")){
                    googleMap.clear();
                    new GeocoderTask(MainActivityMap.this).execute(location);

                }
```

My Geocoder Asynctask Activity

```
        private class GeocoderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Address>>{
            private Context mainContxt;
            Geocoder geocoder;
            public GeocoderTask(Context con){
            mainContxt=con;

            } 

            @Override
            protected List<Address> doInBackground(String... locationName) {
                 Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(mainContxt);
                    List<Address> addresses = null;

                    try {
                        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locationName[0], 3);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return addresses;
            }


            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(List<Address> addresses) { 


        if(addresses==null || addresses.size()==0){
      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Location found.Please check       

      address", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      return; // add this
       }
      else{

               for(int i=0;i<addresses.size();i++){             

                    Address address = (Address) addresses.get(i);
                    latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());

                    String addressText = String.format("%s, %s",
                            address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? address.getAddressLine(0) : "",
                            address.getCountryName());

                    markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                    markerOptions.position(latLng);
                    markerOptions.title(addressText);
                    if(i==0)    {
                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng)); 
                    }
                    googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);


               }
             }
           }
        }
```

i think error in this line

```
  addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locationName[0], 3);
```

address dosent receive anything
....thx in advance...help me friends

Comment: Why you not use Longitude and Latitude for this??

Comment: @chirag how to use latitude and longitude in this activity

Comment: my question is that why address receive null value......when i m sending it

Comment: use this addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);

Comment: and you can get longitude and latitude like this.... Location location = googleMap.getMyLocation();   // latitude = location.getLatitude();
      // longitude = location.getLongitude();

Comment: @chirag you forget i m reciving in protected List<Address> doInBackground(String... locationName) {
               so how we can get location lattitude and lattitude

Comment: I know that, But I only suggest you that you can store longitude and latitude when you getting address... and after that you can easily use longitude and latitude for set pin at particular address..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my App I use This code to get Address...!!! This is for your reference.

```
Geocoder geocoder;
    List<Address> addresses;
    double latitude, longitude;
    String zip, city, state, country;
    googleMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onMapLongClick(LatLng arg0) {

                    latitude = arg0.latitude;
                    longitude = arg0.longitude;
                    String title = "";
                    geocoder = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
                    try {
                        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
                            zip = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
                            city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                            state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
                            country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                            if (zip != null) {
                                title += zip + ",";
                            }
                            if (city != null) {
                                title += city + ",";
                            }
                            if (state != null) {
                                title += state + ",";
                            }
                            if (country != null) {
                                title += country;
                            }
                        } else {
                            title = "Unknown Location";
                            showPosition.setText("Address Not Found");
                        }

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
    // This will put marker and set Address as a marker title
                    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(arg0).title(title));


                }
            });
```

how to set marker in google map?

```
 MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(shortDescStr);
                googleMap.addMarker(options);
```

Comment: i know this can be correct but it dosent help me because i want to set marker by default ..i m fetching value from json and pass to Geocoder

Comment: but why adresss reciieve null value.....i send defalut value from new GeocoderTask(MainActivityMap.this).execute(location);
and in location i set default value